# Sqlite administration tool for inserting images from the file system ? (OSX or Linux)

Tags: sqlite, blob, database-tools

Is there a free sqlite administration tool that let me easily insert/update images from the file system as blobs in certain tables ?. 
I am looking for a tool compatible with OSX and/or Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlite-manager

Extension for Firefox and other apps to manage any sqlite database

http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/